# Async.sequence implementation

Tags: functional-programming, asynchronous, f#

I have a simple implementation for "`Async.sequence`" (the name came [from here](https://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/elevated-world-4/#sequence)), but I would like someone to review it for performance, tail call optimization, and functional style.

It has the following signature, which is similar to `Async.Parallel`:

```
Async<'a> list -> Async<'a list>
```

`Async.Parallel` would be ideal for performance, but it may be important to run the operations in order even though they happen to be async.

```
let sequence list =
    let rec loop l acc =
        async {
            match l with
            | [] ->
                return List.rev acc
            | h::t ->
                let! h' = h
                return! loop t (h'::acc)
        }
    loop list []
```

**Update**

I came up with a minimal implementation built from other basic operations: `map` + `apply` (to get `map2`) and `retn`. `cons` is just a helper for the `::` operation, since that is not actually a function in F#.

```
let sequenceList list =
    List.foldBack (map2 cons) list (retn [])
```

It is probably better to use a library already built, but I like defining these functions myself to better understand how the operations relate. Now that I have the formulation of `sequence`, I can literally copy and paste this code into my Result module which also has its own `map2` and `retn` defined, and it will work the same.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell, this should be properly tail-call optimized (see [this post](http://fsharpnews.blogspot.cz/2010/10/memory-leaks-in-asynchronous-workflows.html)), but I haven't actually checked.

---

Consider using [`AsyncSeq`](http://fsprojects.github.io/FSharp.Control.AsyncSeq/library/AsyncSeq.html), it could make dealing with asynchronous collections easier.

Comment: I may consider AsyncSeq, but so far `sequence` is the only Async/List combination I've needed and I didn't see a function in that library to address it.